# Почему dbConnection остаётся null?

Tags: java

Ругается на то, что база данных не существует. Действительно, `dbConnection` почему-то так и остаётся `null`.

```
public class CreatingConnection {

    private static Connection getDBConnection() {
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql::port/db","postgres", "user");
            return dbConnection;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return dbConnection;
    }
    static void createDbUserTable() throws SQLException {
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        Statement statement = null;

        String createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE DBUSER("
                + "USER_ID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, "
                + "USERNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, "
                + "MESSAGE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, "
                + ")";

        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            System.out.println(dbConnection);
            statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
            statement.execute(createTableSQL);
            System.out.println("Table \"dbuser\" is created!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }
            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы параметры подключения проверяли? И база данных точно существует? Вы к ней каким-то инным способом пробовали подключиться, используя те же данные?

Comment: `:postgresql::port/db` вот тут ошибка. укажите корректные данные.  postgresql - это адрес базы, где она лежит, port - порт(число), db - имя схемы(базы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:postgresql::port/db` вот тут ошибка. укажите корректные данные.

`postgresql` - это адрес базы, где она лежит,

`port` - порт(число),

`db` - имя схемы(базы)

пример,

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testdb", "mkyong",
                "123456");
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!) теперь ругается
No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgesql://127.0.0.1:5432/db

Comment: У тебя схема называется db? у тебя зависимости все имеются ?